# Is it acceptable for an employment contract to cover any activity?

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts

I am about to take up a new position with a company and they have sent me over a contract to sign. One of the clauses of the contract is headed "Competition" and consists of a paragraph that given the normal grammatical understanding of commas the sentence could be read as follows:

> You will not, while employed by the Company, be engaged or interested in any  activity without the express permission in writing of the company.

... *any* activity... like eating a meal or driving my car?

I have queried this with the HR department of the company in question and they have said that the clause is non-optional and that it is specifically not limited just to commercial activity.

I have never come across something this broad before. It seems very strange to me that a company would use a contract to grant itself purview over every single activity I could possibly engage in, inside and outside of the employment but is this considered acceptable within the course of normal employment? Maybe I am misunderstanding the scope of the paragraph?

EDIT: per comments request for jurisdiction information, we can say this in the UK (currently still part of the EU for now).

Comment: If you do not understand a contract. I suggest you contact a lawyer. How effective contract are depend on a lot of things, including region (I could not sign away my rights even if I wanted to)

Comment: @heroen I dont _think_ it's that I don't understand the contract, HR have said this broadness is correct and intended. My question asks, is such broadness generally considered acceptable?

Comment: Then I suggest you change the title to reflect this "How broadly can contract clauses apply?" is a legal question. Whatever it's generally considered acceptable seems to be an answerable question. However I still suggest adding your country/state as that will be relevant to any answer. I have to add, this would be to broad for me to sign. You could not even follow any education without permission. I would never sign a contract that has any effect on my personal life (including for example who I could date)

Comment: Suppose you are interested or engaged in sports. Does the contract mean that you need the company's written permission to be engaged in that?

Comment: IANAL, but this sounds so broad that they could fire you for volunteering at your local church/synagogue/mosque/temple.

Comment: IANAL but I do know the broader the terms the harder it is for them to enforce.  It also says you cannot even be interested in any other business. 
 Asking you to sign such a broad term is not a good sign.  I still have to VTC as legal.

Comment: @Toby "HR have said this broadness is correct" - Legally, it could be a different matter. If a clause is unenforceable, it's possible that you could sign it anyway with low risk (you could pretend it is not there), but you should get a lawyer to look it over to tell you the risks. You could also push back and negotiate that the sentence be removed. You might risk losing the job offer.

Comment: @Jeroen, Thanks for clarifying, Have edited title per your recommendation

Comment: @Paparazzi What does VTC mean?

Comment: @toby Vote To Close

Comment: IANAL - but you can put anything into a contract, but that doesn't necessarily make it remotely enforceable...or legal.

Comment: @Tim Correct, but they can still fire you based on that.

Comment: The only negative thing I see is as other said that the contract is very broad. If you volunteer for a church, for example, you might get fired for breech of contract. The way I understood "activity" is where you engage your time in a business or company (ex. Volunteering, participating in a hackaton, etc). Obviously it doesn't mean something like eating. Overall if you don't understand a legal document, it is always wise to consult a lawyer. Even if unlawful or unenforceable, you're still bounded by the contract and could be fired.

Comment: This is where you walk away.  Seriously, if this is how they "Open the door," what do you think working there will be like?

Comment: @Toby I didn't read your earlier comment. If HR is saying this broad term is intended, then I would do as other said to walk away. I don't think it's as broad as what you eat, or what you do, but I do think it touch upon activities you engage at home like volunteering or even something like doing open source. Usually the contract would say don't engage in jobs/tasks for a competing company.

Comment: @Dan not in the UK they can't leagly fire anyone for that illegally yes but that would be an automatic lose in court

Comment: > "I have never come across something this broad before." - it's not unheard of. I have had jobs where **after** being hired they pulled out a contract (threat) that doubled the workload and wanted me to agree to not work for the competition for a period of years; I simply asked for double the wages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm..I think as Jeroen says in his comment this is really a question for a lawyer - many jurisdictions have limitations on the ability of a contract (particularly employment contracts) to restrict you, but that's not something we can really answer here.

In terms of whether this sort of all-encompassing clause is *normal* or not I would have to say **no**.

Clauses restricting what you can do in a business sense are pretty common. Even ones restricting non-business activities that could potentially affect the company aren't unheard of - I've known of ones that restrict an employee from engaging in dangerous sports or hobbies that may result in them becoming injured and unable to fulfill their role for example, or the increasingly common terms preventing you from posting certain things on social media if they would be detrimental to the company's reputation, but *any* activity? That's a new one on me - and while I can't imagine something so broad would stand a chance of being enforceable I think most people would reject such a broad clause.

It may be that they have a particular scope for the word "activity" in mind that narrows this to a more reasonable outlook but that's not clear from what you've said. I'd suggest putting the ball back in their court and asking them what they consider to be an "activity" under this term.

**EDIT:** Following the update that this is in the UK I thought I'd add in that not only is such a broad term definitely unusual (I'm in the UK and have never seen one so broad) but also (with the usual disclaimer of IANL and this is not legal advice) they wouldn't stand a snowball's chance in hell of enforcing it. There's no hard and fast rule on what they are allowed to prohibit out of working hours (apart from anything protected by discrimination legislation such as religion, sexuality etc) but generally they have to convince the court that the activity harms the organisation's business or reputation (or the other staff as they have a duty of care) and these things get evaluated on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: The ultimate goal of the contract is employability. If you breech it, then the worst case is being fired. In most US states, an employer can fire without any reason so a contract is just icing on a cake that doesn't mean anything. Now if they want to hold you accountable legally like paying back money, etc, then yeah, enforceability or legality comes into question which in most cases cannot be enforced since you performed your duty until the breech.

Comment: One thing to consider, If they are putting things this unreasonable in the contract (whether enforceable or not), then it is highly likely the corporate culture is unreasonable in general. I would turn down the offer unless I was unemployed and need the job to continue to have a roof over my head.

Comment: @Dan actually I believe there can be more severe penalties for breach of contract than just being fired - but IANL

Comment: In general its even harder to enforce noncompetes in the UK than states like CA

Comment: @Neuromancer very much so - although that is generally only the case when it's being applied after you have left. I can't remember the official name for it but there's generally a view from the courts that you can't restrict someone from earning a living. Non-competes are difficult (and expensive) to enforce via the courts so generally they are there to discourage people from more egregious examples or a bluff to strengthen the companies negotiating position when someone valuable is leaving

Comment: @motosubatsu True, there are cases where people got prison time for breech of contract. However, you'd have to go really, really out of your way in blatant disregard. Volunteering at church for a weekend and getting fired for breech of contract on a vague term wouldn't land you in prison and the company asking for money returned would never pass any court in any 1st world country that I know of.

Comment: @Dan oh I agree.. it has to be pretty extreme, and they would have to prove substantial damage to the company as a result to get anything beyond a simple firing but it *is* possible

Comment: @Dan never heard of an employee in the UK doing time for breach of contract its a civil offence not a criminal one and I am an experienced lay TU activist.

Comment: @Neuromancer not *directly* but with a bit of legal maneuvering you *can* end up in prison as a [result](http://www.renneyandco.co.uk/blog/2017-07-16/breach-of-contract-employee-lands-up-in-jail), technically in that case the custodial sentence is as a result of breaching a court order that was put in place to enforce the contract which is considered "Contempt of court" and that's the offence the guy went to jail for.

Comment: @motosubatsu that's for theft of trade secrets not a non compete I suspect the lawyers have carefully written that article to help market themselves.

Comment: @Neuromancer Apologies for any confusion, I wasn't intending to imply that my link was referring to a non-compete merely that it was an example of a civil breach of an employment contract ultimately leading to a custodial sentence after it was enforced by a court order (which was then subsequently breached). The case received a moderate amount of coverage at the time and the link I posted just happened to be the first that came up when I went digging to refresh myself on it but it reflects the situation and judgement pretty accurately.